# Working by remote, without accessing to sensitive informations

Tags: metadata, data, org

Suppose one has to work on the **structure** of an org (for introducing some change), but it is not possible to access to the informations contained in the org itself for security reasons. For example it is not possible to see the names and the revenues of the Accounts, and so on.

Is it possible to give access to the "structure" of an org without accessing to the dates? In other words, can I access to a *cleaned* org?

ps= I hope this question makes sense to you...!

Comment: You can create a sandbox environment, which can be a copy of your live org but without any data in it.

Comment: Is possible that the company does not have a Sandbox? Or there always be a Sandbox corresponding to a production license?

Comment: I believe only organizations licensed for Enterprise Edition and higher get a sandbox without explicitly licensing one.

Comment: I've seen custom 'admin' profiles with no data access, but it makes it pretty hard to test anything if you can't see data.  Creating a sandbox would be the best option, especially if you're making changes.  Are you making changes to Production without a development environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sandbox environment, which can be a copy of your live org but without any data in it.

There are different kinds of sandbox: Developer; Developer Pro; Partial Copy; Full. Note that Developer sandbox is a different thing from the free Developer org that you can get.

All of the sandboxes will have the metadata from Production, i.e. the "Structure".

The simplest sandbox is Developer and it does not copy any of the Production data and has the smallest amount of space available. Typically this sandbox would be used by a Developer to develop and test new functionality before deploying it - either to a fuller sandbox for more testing, or directly to Production.

If you log in to your Org and click Setup | Sandboxes you will see what sandboxes are available under your current license agreement.

Comment: Doug, first of all thanks for your answer. Second: if the company has a Professional Edition, is it possible that they do NOT have any Sandboxes? Neither the Sandbox Developer? Is it costly to buy one?

Comment: From the look of this http://www.sfdcstatic.com/uk/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf I believe that developer pro sandboxes are available for Professional Edition, but at an additional cost. So it would be possible for a company to have PE and not have a sandbox I think. Equally, it would be possible for that company to stay on PE and add a sandbox by paying for it.